# Мерцание монитора (особенно после обновлений)

Tags: linux, windows, администрирование, ноутбук, монитор

Иногда, особенно часто после ребута после обновления, монитор мерцает при включении ноута. Это происходит как на линуксе в терминале, так и в GUI винды. Проходит после захода и выхода из сна (дампа оперативки на диск и обратно). С чем это может быть связано?

Вроде бы это не системная проблема, раз на обеих осях происходит, но и непонятно почему учащается именно после обновлений (как линукса, так и винды), если она железная. Также на ноуте установлены 2 видеокарты: встроенная Intel и внешняя Nvidia. Может они как-то конфликтуют. Драйвера все свежие, на линухе постоянно обновляется проприетарный nvidia-драйвер.

Любые идеи приветствуются.

Фотография не моя, но выглядит примерно так же.

[image]

Comment: включаю-выключаю монитор в таких случаях)

Comment: @eri вхождение в сон также отключает монитор, не знаю, как отдельно его отключить (уменьшение яркости до минимума и обратно не помогает вроде бы). Ещё с тестированием проблема -- не могу стабильно вызвать мерцание, чтобы проверять всевозможные пути отключения монитора :)

Comment: `xset dpms force off` Turn off screen immediately
`xset dpms force standby` Standby screen
`xset dpms force suspend` Suspend screen

Comment: @eri спасибо, забинжу на какую-нибудь кнопку и проверю, когда опять появится мерцание

Comment: @eri да, простое отключение-включение экрана без сна также помогает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ранее у меня был монитор с VGA разъемом, на нем была такая же проблема, в итоге оказалось что один VGA провод был в плачевном состоянии и был сильно пережат.

- У VGA часто такая проблема бывает. Попробуйте другой провод.
- Еще возможно, что nVidia где-то накосячила. Недавно обновление драйверов у них было, после них рендеринг с помощью видеокарты в Premiere Pro стал работать с ошибками. Попробуйте откатить драйвера.
- Может быть еще рассинхрон у монитора с герцовкой. Например у монитора 60 герц, а подается 59 герц
- Ну или возможно монитору хана (с контроллером позиции)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 1) не может быть, т.к. ноут со "встроенным" монитором, а не кабелем 2) такая ситуация наблюдается уже длительное время, т.е. если баг в драйверах Nvidia, то его очень долго не правят + этот баг должен быть и в Linux, и в Windows 3) и 4) варианты изучу подробнее

Answer (score 3):

Похохе аппаратный рассинхрон генератора частоты на мониторе и компе.

При отставании генератора на микросекунды ошибка накапливается к середине монитора и присходит сброс строки на следующую.

Помогает перезапуск питания монитора. Скорее всего связанно со старением и потерей характеристик на электрокомпонентах, скорее всего конденсаторов. Такое предположение потому как эффект не воспроизводится на прогретом мониторе.